# What replaced the pmap_set command?

Tags: rpc, honeypot

Hi I am trying to set up the tiny honeypot on my laptop. I'm at the part of the process where you install fake service translations. The command calls for [pmap_set](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pmap_set). After portmap was replaced with rpcbind, what took its place? As in, how do I use the equivalent with rpc (library routines for remote procedure calls)? I'm trying to change the rpcinfo output I believe.

Comment: Please add more details on the operating system you are using, why you are setting up a Honeypot.

Comment: I'm using arch linux and why do most people use a honeypot?